# 'From a dream' = Ex somnium / somnus?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, translation-check

(I've never posted on StackExchange before so sorry if I'm missing any tags etc.)

I'm currently tasked with some creative writing tasks and have been asked to title a work dealing with nightmares (specifically figures crossing from dreams into the real world).

I'm looking to find a good Latin translation for **'from a dream'** (I'm toying with the idea of something in the vein of [deus ex machina](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deus_ex_machina)) but am unsure on how Latin declension works (I'm an ex-linguist so this is very embarrassing for me).

Any and all suggestions welcome! Thanks :)

Comment: Thank you for your post! It's always nice to see new contributors. So help me help you -- I'm bit confused about what "in the vein of Deus ex Machina" means to you. Do you mean a dream is accomplishing something by fiat? It would be helpful if I had a bit more context to work from.

Comment: @Nickimite, I simply interpreted the OP such that when he wondered how to express *X from Y* in Latin, he remembered the phrase *deus ex machina* and thought: if it works with *machina*, it should work with other words as well. Which reasoning is sound :)

Comment: I did indeed mean in the sense of how to express X from Y. Apologies if that wasn't clear - was very overworked last night!

Comment: Ex typically takes the ablative, and dream is "somnium" so "Ex somnio" would be correct.

Answer (score 6):

*Somnus* means "sleep". *Somnium* means "dream". One need not be an (ex) linguist to see these words are related, but they are distinct words with different meanings. I suppose you could work with both, but since you explicitly asked for "dream", I would recommend *somnium*.

Now *ex* is a preposition that always requires the ablative case. You can easily find the oblique forms (i.e. the forms of a word that are different from the dictionary form) at [Wiktionary](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/somnium). From this we see that the ablative singular is *somnio* and the plural would be *somniis*.

Thus we can construct:

- **ex somnio** *from a/the dream*
- **ex somniis** *from (the) dreams*

(At this point you may be wondering: Hey, what about *deus ex machina*? No ablative there? It's the ablative too, but you only see it when vowel length is denoted in writing; the ablative of *māchina* is *māchinā*, and the expression is: *deus ex māchinā*. You would also hear the difference in spoken form if the speaker does correctly render vowel length, which in this case, even with experienced Latin speakers, is a bit hit-and-miss.)

There is also the adjective **somnurnus**, which is rare, but understood to be analogous to *nocturnus* etc., meaning: "belonging to sleep". In particular, the only use I find is: *imagines somnurnae*, meaning: "sights seen in sleep" - i.e., presumably when dreaming. The singular would be *imago somnurna*. But you can get creative and write: *res somnurna* (thing from the dreams) or *animans somnurnum* (being; I'd avoid *animal*, though that would work also), etc.

Comment: Thank you so much for this! I have settled on 'ex somnio' :) Clearly I need to start re-reading my notes from historical linguitics!

Answer (score -3):

When speaking about the product of something or some person, the word used is the preposition *de*, which means handed down from. So, if some idea comes from a dream, then it would be *sententia de somnio*. There is a famous book by Cicero entitled *De Somnio Scipionis*, Of a Dream of Scipio.

The word *ex* is used when something physically exits another physical object. The difference is whether something is being *produced*, or is merely *exiting*.